# remove or ignore double quotes in a string - powershell

Tags: powershell, command-line, double-quotes

I think I have a simple problem but I can't seem to find the answer.

This is a part of the string I am working with

```
$text = "INDEPENDENT ELECTORAL AND BOUNDARIES COMMISSION
POLLING STATION: "ABC DEF GHIJKL (001)" 
STREAM:123"
```

When I try to work with this, I get an error because of the double quotes in $text. I know I can escape the double quotes using a back tick, but the entire string is too big for me to go through it all.

I wonder if there is a simple way to ignore or remove all double (and single, too) quotes except for the first and last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by using here-strings:

```
$Text = @'
All the symbols I/ can ` hope for
between " the *>$ opening $() and closing ${}
of the symbols
'@
```

Comment: The last `'@` must be on its own line with no leading characters.

Comment: Thanks @JasonBoyd I couldn't remember whether it was the first or last.

Comment: @JasonBoyd: Acceptance of TheIncorrigible's answer will be appreciable if it helps you.

Comment: @RanadipDutta It's not my question to accept an answer to.

Comment: @JasonBoyd: Lolz . i overlooked it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use this: `@' ... '@`

Your string would look like this:

```
$text = @'
"INDEPENDENT ELECTORAL AND BOUNDARIES COMMISSION
POLLING STATION: "ABC DEF GHIJKL (001)" 
STREAM:123"
'@
```